# SSH not working on freshed installed Rasperry Pi OS with enabled ssh in Rasperry PI Imager

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, ssh, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, raspberry-pi-imager

I have the Raspberry Pi 4B (2GB) and I'm trying to configure it **without using a desktop environment**.

I'm using the official Raspberry Pi Imager v1.7.1. I'm installing Rasperry PI OS Lite (64bit). In the advanced options I enabled SSH, set a username and password and my wifi's settings.

After flashing the microSD card and starting the pi, the pi successfully connects to my wifi (i can see that on my router's dashboard).

But connecting via ssh always fails. ssh is certainly running on the rasperry pi, because I always get to the point, where the password gets prompted. When I enter the password, the rasperry pi always behaves as if the password has been entered incorrectly.

```
harry@weatherpi's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

*I am absolutely sure that I am entering the password correctly.* I have flashed several times with different passwords, nothing works.

Does anyone have a suggestion how I can identify what is going wrong there (using my microSD card)?

Answer (score -1):

Oh what a shame! I forget entering the username while connecting via ssh!
I typed `ssh weatherpi` but I should have used `ssh pi@weatherpi`.